# Bootstrapping app in Angular 2 RC 5

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services

As I understood now I should use modules for bootstrapping. But now I couldn't understand how should I provide custom providers?

Example from RC 4:

```
bootstrap(
  ....
  {
     provide : Router,
     useClass: SomeClass
  },
  {
     provide : API_URL,
     useValue: "awesome url"
  },
  {
     provide : AUTH_URL,
     useValue: "other awesome url"
  }
)
```

How can I pass this params in new bootstrapping system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    routing,
    HttpModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    HeroSearchComponent
  ],
  providers: [ // <=== THIS
    HeroService,
    { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: InMemoryBackendService }, // in-mem server
    { provide: SEED_DATA,  useClass: InMemoryDataService }     // in-mem server data
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

where `providers` specify **custom providers**

Check updated *Tour of Heroes* https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-6/ts/plnkr.html

Comment: Thanks. I still doesn't understand why they added modules.

Comment: **Angular Modules** help organize an application into cohesive blocks of functionality (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html). I, personally, like this a lot.

Comment: I was reading it. But I have a good organization with Component. But who am I to tell them what to do =)